# “Alarming given” meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

From a [recent science article](https://www.newscientist.com/upfront/3153/):

> Jonathan Watkins of King’s College London and colleagues found that after controlling for other economic changes, death rates rose after the cuts, especially among the over 65s.
>
> The two events were statistically associated in time, which doesn’t formally prove cause and effect, the team notes. But excess deaths correlated most closely with a lack of nurses in care homes and cuts to community nursing.
>
> This is **alarming given** that a bad flu season is expected to strike the UK soon, and people over 65 are the most likely to die from flu.

I want to detect the meaning of the phrase “alarming given”? 
Is given a noun here? 
If it is a noun, i think it should be an alarming given because given is countable.

Could it be this way:
(This is alarming) [which is] given <sub>participle adjective</sub> that ...?

Comment: A little more context might be required. Can you add a little more context or provide us with some source?

Comment: I added additional information to the text. @VarunNair

Comment: I've added a punctuation to make it clearer. "_this is alarming, given that a bad flu season is expected to strike the UK soon..._"

Comment: Your second parsing is correct.  "Alarming given" isn't one phrase; it's "this is alarming / given that ____"

Comment: @BavyanY: Please read [why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Given that X" means that X is the background information that provides context to what is stated.

The text above the sentence in question (in the quoted article) is "(...)  excess deaths correlated most closely with a lack of nurses in care homes and cuts to community nursing." That is what "this is alarming" refers to. So the text should be understood as follows:

1. (Background) a bad flu season is expected to strike the UK soon, and people over 65 are the most likely to die from flu.
2. (Statement) when we are given the knowledge that a flu season is expected to strike the UK soon, this [=the lack of nurses which is correlated to excess death] is alarming.

Answer (score 2):

"Given that.." simply means "Granted that.." and has no particular significance placed next to "alarming" in this context.

You could easily rewrite this as:

> "This is alarming *granted that* a bad flu season is expected to strike
>   the UK soon..."

In other words, the circumstance is alarming when you consider that a bad flu season is expected to strike the UK soon.

Answer (score 0):

Another interpretation of '**given**' in this context could be: **considering** or **take something into account**.

"*This is alarming given that ..."* is like saying "*This is alarming, considering the fact that ...* "